# iOS CoreBluetooth get unique peripheral ID

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

In iOS, I'm using CoreBluetooth and trying to maintain a list of detected bluetooth peripherals but the uuids keep changing and the list becomes obsolete.

Is there a way to retrieve the unique peripheral id that don't change?

There are other similar questions here but none of them helped solve the problem.

Comment: If you pair with the device it shouldn't change, else, it's the behavior of iOS to avoid that tracking. Else, you can have a char with a unique ID and read it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to initiate pairing from iOS?

Comment: By reading a encrypted property. But not all BLE devices are for pairing (or even have that feature).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by pairing with the peripheral.

Comment: hi, you can explain please ?